# Can I install using GPT on 32 bit system with bios?

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation, gpt, bios, partition-table

All I search for this says, makes me understand that GPT is related to UEFI, but is it possible to install using GPT disk format, in a 32 bit system using bios (not legacy mode)?
I tried installing Arch in a VM simulating 32bit and using a partition like:

```
-BBP
/boot
/
/home
swap
```

and it did not work.
Is it possible? If it is, is that the correct partitioning using BBP?
Maybe it's cause I tried encrypting the / and /home without using LVM following the Arch guide, but i'm not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### You can do it.

GPT and (U)EFI are not related concepts, although it is only custom that (U)EFIs use GPT partition tables, or at least they are compatible with them.

The BIOS (typically) can't see partitions, and the partition tables only rarely affect it. The only what the BIOS knows if that it has to read the first sector of the MBR (=the first sector of the disk) and then execute the code fragment in it.

Some BIOSes do also additional checks (checksum validities, the existence of the bootable flag, partition limits in the partition table) as so on, some not. However, GPT is *backward compatible* to the traditional partitioning, so it won't be a problem.

More exactly, a GPT partition table *not* being compatible with a traditional one, is invalid.

The only what you have to do is to somehow "help" your installer to create a GPT layout (what may be problematic).